# DJI Onboard-SDK to Mobile-SDK communication: Issues with mobile side using swift

Tags: swift, dji-sdk

I am currently working on a project that that involves data to be sent from a third party computer on a DJI UAV, to an IOS app. I have successfully implemented the sending of data on the Onboard-SDK, but am having trouble with receiving the sent data on the Mobile-SDK. The mobile app is written in swift. There are examples of receiving data from UAV on IOS(in documentation), but they are all written in objective C.

I honestly cannot find a single other person who has experience with this. Is there anyone who has done this, or something similar? Any answer would be helpful.

Documentation example of receiving data on mobile device (objective C):

```
(void)flightController:(DJIFlightController *_Nonnull)fc 
didReceiveDataFromOnboardSDKDevice:(NSData *_Nonnull)data;
```

Let me know if you need more context to help.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385943/how-do-i-convert-uint8-data-from-the-dji-onboard-sdk ? What's your issue about the receiving? Interpret the data like the other question? If yes, is there code that transform `data` into something we can't guess what it should look like?

Comment: I didn't phrase my question well. I am starting back from the beginning with receiving the data. My problem has actually changed. The function "fc 
didReceiveDataFromOnboardSDKDevice", is not even in the api, I searched the DJIflight controller component header file and it is nowhere to be found. So I am basically calling something that doesn't exist, and thats what gives me the error. However this example is used in their own documentation. Are you able to find this function in the MSDK? I am really confused on how its not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flight controller has a public property exposed on it called onboardSDKDevice which has a delegate called DJIOnboardSDKDeviceDelegate and one of the methods is - (void)onboardSDKDevice:(DJIOnboardSDKDevice *)osdkDevice didSendDataToMobile:(NSData *)data;  You should be able to set the delegate to your class and implement that method to get the NSData.

Comment: @LarryYourWaiter can you point me to where the documentation is out of date so we can update it?